# Adding constraint to check if the value contains specific characters- SQL Server

Tags: sql

My Check constraint conflicts when adding values, any answer to why it is wrong will be much appreciated.

Here is the question:

> Ensure that the Student’s NIC number contains 9 digits (0-9) and one
> character which is “V” or “v”.

Here is the value I want to add to the table:

```
946785467v
```

Here is the constraint I used:

```
ALTER TABLE Student
ADD CONSTRAINT stdNIC CHECK(NIC LIKE '[0-9]{9}[V-v]');
```

Comment: Please include your SQL _version_, such as MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.  The answer you want is very vendor specific.

Comment: It is your goal to only check if the string contains both 9 digits and one "v" or do you even want to exactly check whether the "v" is the last character of your string?

Comment: A further question: Should inserting null values be prevented? I'm adding this question since the given answer does not prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Better to change the constraint as below.

```
ALTER TABLE Student ADD CONSTRAINT stdNIC CHECK(NIC LIKE '%[0-9]%[V-v]')
```

Example validated on [db<>fiddle<>example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7c0465cd79c9d79bd1855c047d2b05f)